# It It Possible to modify the contents of the navigation menu using CSOM

Tags: development, navigation, csom

I have a large number of subsites that are similar. I want to make a global change to the sidebar navigation menu on all of these subsites. By change i want to add a new link. I have looked and i cannot seem to find anycode to help me do this.

Im using Sharepoint 2013 with CSOM and C#, but help with any programming language would be great to get me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the *quick launch*. You may wanna try this code -

```
private static void AddNode(string url)

    {
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext(url);

        context.Load(context.Web);

        //Fetching website's Left Navigation node collection

        NavigationNodeCollection qlNavNodeColl = context.Web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;

        //Create a new node

    NavigationNodeCreationInformation newNavNode = new NavigationNodeCreationInformation();

    newNavNode.Title = "Google";

    newNavNode.Url = "https://www.google.com"; //URL must always start with http/https

    qlNavNodeColl.Add(newNavNode);

    try
    {
        context.ExecuteQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //Handle exception
    }
}
```

Source : [Add/Update/Delete nodes from QuickLaunch](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/987078/Add-Update-Delete-nodes-from-QuickLaunch-Current-N)